# How to make a node inside a node using tinyxml2?

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

```
XMLDocument xmlDoc;

XMLNode * pRoot = xmlDoc.NewElement("Head");
xmlDoc.InsertFirstChild(pRoot);
XMLElement * pElement = xmlDoc.NewElement("Stat1");
pElement-> SetText(10);
pRoot->InsertEndChild(pElement);
pElement = xmlDoc.NewElement("Stat2");
pElement->SetText(0.5);
pRoot->InsertEndChild(pElement);

XMLNode *   pRoot2 = xmlDoc.NewElement("Head2");
xmlDoc.InsertAfterChild(pRoot, pRoot2);
XMLElement * pElement2 = xmlDoc.NewElement("Stat3");
pElement2-> SetText(10);
pRoot2->InsertEndChild(pElement2);

XMLError eResult = xmlDoc.SaveFile("SavedData.xml");
XMLCheckResult(eResult);
```

The above code will produce an xml file with following xml structure

```
<Head>
  <Stat1>10</Stat1>
  <Stat2>0.5</Stat2>
 </Head>

<Head2>
  <Stat3>10</Stat3>
</Head2>
```

But i wanted my desire xml structure to be like

```
<root>
  <Head>
    <inner-Head>
      <Stat1>10</Stat1>
    </inner-Head>

    <inner-Head2>
      <Stat2>0.5</Stat2>
    </inner-Head2>
  </Head>

  <Head2>
    <Stat3>10</Stat3>
  </Head2>
</root>
```

I am new to tinyxml2 and could not find any tinyxml2 tutorials,what i wanted to achieve is to have a node inside a node as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process to create nodes and subnodes un tinyxml2 es pretty much recursive: i.e., once you create one, you know how to create the remaining ones.

My advice is to just follow the hierarchy top-down, until you reach the leafs. This way you will only need to use *InsertEndChild()*. Also, you should use descriptive names for your nodes.

The only difference is that to create the root node, you have to use **XMLDoc**.*InsertEndChild()*, while in the remaining cases you receive a pointer to the node, and therefore you have to use the arrow for **XMLNode**.*InsertEndChild()*.

You want to have a "root" node in the document. Then:

```
XMLDocument xmlDoc;

XMLNode * nRoot = xmlDoc.NewElement( "root" );
xmlDoc.InsertEndChild( nRoot );
```

Then you want to have to "Head"'s, hanging from root. So:

```
XMLNode * nHead = xmlDoc.NewElement( "Head" );
XMLNode * nHead2 = xmlDoc.NewElement( "Head2" );
nRoot->InsertEndChild( nHead );
nRoot->InsertEndChild( nHead2 );
```

So far so good. Inside "Head", you want two "inner-Heads". Then:

```
XMLNode * nInnerHead = xmlDoc.NewElement( "inner-Head" );
XMLNode * nInnerHead2 = xmlDoc.NewElement( "inner-Head2" );
nHead->InsertEndChild( nInnerHead );
nHead->InsertEndChild( nInnerHead2 );
```

And finally, the leafs inside *inner-Head* and *inner-Head2*:

```
XMLElement * pElement = xmlDoc.NewElement( "Stat1" );
pElement-> SetText( 10 );    
nInnerHead->InsertEndChild( pElement );

pElement = xmlDoc.NewElement( "Stat2" );
pElement->SetText( 0.5 );
nInnerHead2->InsertEndChild( pElement );
```

The other branch, in *Head2*, is even easier, since only one leaf hangs from it:

```
pElement = xmlDoc.NewElement( "Stat3" );
pElement->SetText( 10 );
nHead2->InsertEndChild( pElement );
```

And you obtain the desired result:

```
<root>
<Head>
    <inner-Head>
        <Stat1>10</Stat1>
    </inner-Head>
    <inner-Head2>
        <Stat2>0.5</Stat2>
    </inner-Head2>
</Head>
<Head2>
    <Stat3>10</Stat3>
</Head2>
</root>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this helps alot!